A question on proving that power iteration is contracting
I have a question, how to derive the inequality result marked with red in the picture, which is from the paper - A Converse to Banach’s Fixed Point Theorem and Its CLS-Completeness.
The picture is mainly to show that power iteration is contracting with a special metric.
Thanks so much!
enter image description here

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.
